# scp or rsync analogue for cp -T (treat target as file)

Tags: rsync, scp

With `cp` I can:

```
$ mkdir q
$ touch s
$ cp -T s q  # I need same effect with scp and/or rsync.
cp: cannot overwrite directory 'q' with non-directory
$ ls q
```

How do I get same effect in one command with `scp` and/or `rsync`? I.e. When target is directory I want it to exit with non-zero exit code without actual file transfer. I don't want file `s` to be placed in directory `q`.

Of course, it can be checked separately. The question is how to do that in one single command. Particularly, for the sake of concurrency.

Comment: Is the issue that there does not exist a single command to do what you wish? In what ways is user DopeGhoti's answer not an acceptable solution?

Comment: @kemotep One command solution is simpler, faster and concurrent. His answer is not accepted because it was clearly stated that I need one command...

Answer (score 0):

This will abort if the remote directory in question exists:

```
if ! ssh user@host "[[ -d /path/to/directory ]]"; then
    # do your scp or rsync
else
    echo "Remote location is a directory.  Aborting." 1&>2
    exit 1
fi
```

If you want to make this into a one-liner, then:

```
ssh user@host "[[ -d /path/to/directory ]]" || <<scp or rsync>>
```

Comment: Currently, I'm doing similar check. I would be great if I had one command solution...

Answer (score 0):

As an option:

```
ssh remote-server 'cat > /tmp/asd' < /tmp/qwe
```

Not a parameter though.

Example:

```
$ ssh localhost 'cat > /tmp/oi' < /tmp/qwe ; echo $?
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
bash: /tmp/oi: Is a directory
Transferred: sent 2832, received 2548 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 60414.8, received 54356.2
1
$ ssh localhost 'cat > /tmp/asd' < /tmp/qwe ; echo $?                                                                                                                                                                     
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
Transferred: sent 2832, received 2496 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 62499.8, received 55084.5
0
$ ls -l /tmp/{qwe,asd,oi}                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-rw-r--r-- 1 george george    4 Apr 19 21:21 /tmp/asd
-rw-r--r-- 1 george george    4 Apr 19 21:19 /tmp/qwe

/tmp/oi:
total 0
```